# Find value of $n$ from difference of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinations

Given that $^nC_3 -$$^nC_2 = 14$, find $n$. There's a method using the Pascal's Triangle, where the $k^{th}$ entry in the $n^{th}$ row is equal to $^nC_k$. Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: if i understand right is this $$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=14$$

Comment: Yes, but this would lead to solving a third degree polynomial equation. The Pascal's triangle method is still easier. Looking for a method that is faster than the Pascal's triangle one.